# In my Root error log I am getting this error - PHP Catchable fatal error

Tags: php

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home//public_html/modules/mod_yoo_login/helper.php on line 23

```
    if($itemid =  $params->get($type))
    {

        $menu =& JSite::getMenu();
        $item = $menu->getItem($itemid);echo "<br>";
        $url = JRoute::_($item->link.'&Itemid='.$itemid, false);
    }
    else
    {
        $url = JURI::base(true);
    }

    return base64_encode($url);
}

function getType()
{
    $user = & JFactory::getUser();
    return (!$user->get('guest')) ? 'logout' : 'login';
}
```

}